# Opening a PDF file as a raw text document

Tags: c#

I have a PDF document which becomes encrypted. During encryption a code is embedded the then end of the filestream before writing to a file.

This PDF is later decrypted and the details are view-able in any PDF viewer.

The issue is the embedded code is also then visible in the decrypted PDF and it needs removing.

I'm looking to decrypt the PDF document, remove the embedded document code then save it to a filename.

```
//Reading the PDF
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("us-ascii");
while ((read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
x = x + enc.GetString(buffer);
}

//Remove the code
x = x.Replace("CODE","");

//Write file
byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes(x);
File.WriteAllBytes(@filePath, bytes);
```

When the original file is generated it appears to be using a different encoder because the first line on the original file reads %PDF-1.6%âãÏÓ and on the decoded file %PDF-1.6 %????.

I have tried ascii, us-ascii, UTF8 and Unicode but upon removal of the embedded CODE the file stoped opening due to corruption. Note the embedded code sits in the raw file after the PDF %%EOF tag.

Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: You don't have to guess what it is, just follow the specs: https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive/PDFReference16.pdf

Comment: thanks ill keep that for reference - resolved it using Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);